# Javascript : Summary of transactions across multiple object properties (groupby, sumby)

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an array of fx transactions across different currencies and exchanges:

```
[  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Canada", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1200},  
{buyCurr: "EUR", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Europe", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 15000},  
{buyCurr: "GBP", sellCurr: "USD", exchange: "NYSE", buyunits: 5000, sellunits: 8000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "BSE", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 180000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "JPY", exchange: "Japan", buyunits: 32000, sellunits: 1000000},  
{buyCurr: "RUB", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "Russia", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1100},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CNY", exchange: "China", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 18000},  
{buyCurr: "CNY", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "China", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 100000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Canada", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1200},  
{buyCurr: "EUR", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Europe", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 15000},  
{buyCurr: "GBP", sellCurr: "USD", exchange: "NYSE", buyunits: 5000, sellunits: 8000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "BSE", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 180000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "JPY", exchange: "Japan", buyunits: 32000, sellunits: 1000000},  
{buyCurr: "RUB", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "Russia", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1100},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CNY", exchange: "China", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 18000},  
{buyCurr: "CNY", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "China", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 100000},  
]
```

I want to summarize my positions across exchanges and currencies. So outcome would look like:

```
[{
    curency : USD,
    exchange: Canada,
    units: 2000
},
{
    curency : CAD,
    exchange: Canada,
    units: -2400
},
{
    curency : USD,
    exchange: NYSE,
    units: -12000
},
......and so on
]
```

Number of units on an exchange is (sum of buyunits for currency(i)) - (sum of sellunits (i)). SO USD will only be offset against USD.

One way to do that I came up with is using forEach to go through every instance, filter on properties and add/reduce buyCurr and sellCurr.

I tried lodash also but it only lets me do groupBy one property.

Is there a better/more efficient way to do it in javascript?

Comment: how about a loop?

Comment: I tried using forEach but code becomes very long so was hoping is there is any better way to do it in javascript as it seems like a common problem.

Comment: your outcome is unclear: how is this `CAD Canada -2400`  calculated? `2000 - 2400` as ((sum of buyunits) - (sum of sellunits)) is not equal to `-2400`

Comment: I updated the expected output. A currency can only be offset by the same currency. So USD can only be subtracted from USD. In the above case, I only made two sell transactions on CAD in exchange 'Canada'  of 1200 each so units = -1200-1200 = -2400.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with one `.reduce` as well. Since you are just adding and subtracting values, you can sum up as you go:

```js
const input=[{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"CAD",exchange:"Canada",buyunits:1e3,sellunits:1200},{buyCurr:"EUR",sellCurr:"CAD",exchange:"Europe",buyunits:1e4,sellunits:15e3},{buyCurr:"GBP",sellCurr:"USD",exchange:"NYSE",buyunits:5e3,sellunits:8e3},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"INR",exchange:"BSE",buyunits:3e3,sellunits:18e4},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"JPY",exchange:"Japan",buyunits:32e3,sellunits:1e6},{buyCurr:"RUB",sellCurr:"INR",exchange:"Russia",buyunits:1e3,sellunits:1100},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"CNY",exchange:"China",buyunits:3e3,sellunits:18e3},{buyCurr:"CNY",sellCurr:"INR",exchange:"China",buyunits:1e4,sellunits:1e5},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"CAD",exchange:"Canada",buyunits:1e3,sellunits:1200},{buyCurr:"EUR",sellCurr:"CAD",exchange:"Europe",buyunits:1e4,sellunits:15e3},{buyCurr:"GBP",sellCurr:"USD",exchange:"NYSE",buyunits:5e3,sellunits:8e3},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"INR",exchange:"BSE",buyunits:3e3,sellunits:18e4},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"JPY",exchange:"Japan",buyunits:32e3,sellunits:1e6},{buyCurr:"RUB",sellCurr:"INR",exchange:"Russia",buyunits:1e3,sellunits:1100},{buyCurr:"USD",sellCurr:"CNY",exchange:"China",buyunits:3e3,sellunits:18e3},{buyCurr:"CNY",sellCurr:"INR",exchange:"China",buyunits:1e4,sellunits:1e5}];

const output = input.reduce( ( sumObj, item ) => {
  const key = `${ item.buyCurr } ${ item.exchange }`;
  sumObj[ key ] = ( sumObj[ key ] || 0 ) + item.buyunits - item.sellunits;
  return sumObj;
}, { /* initial sumObj is going to be an empty object */ } );
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Hi Lumio,  Thanks for your response. I have updated the expected output to make it less ambiguous. I am new to this so just learning :).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to get it all done in one pass, but with some logic in the function, you can run it three times for:

- Buy transactions
- Sell transactions
- Combined transactions

After which you'll have your summarized answers. Not as nice as in one pass, but the function provided is flexible enough to handle all 3 cases:
(You'll need to scroll down to see the full code)

```js
const transactions = [  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Canada", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1200},  
{buyCurr: "EUR", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Europe", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 15000},  
{buyCurr: "GBP", sellCurr: "USD", exchange: "NYSE", buyunits: 5000, sellunits: 8000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "BSE", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 180000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "JPY", exchange: "Japan", buyunits: 32000, sellunits: 1000000},  
{buyCurr: "RUB", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "Russia", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1100},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CNY", exchange: "China", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 18000},  
{buyCurr: "CNY", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "China", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 100000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Canada", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1200},  
{buyCurr: "EUR", sellCurr: "CAD", exchange: "Europe", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 15000},  
{buyCurr: "GBP", sellCurr: "USD", exchange: "NYSE", buyunits: 5000, sellunits: 8000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "BSE", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 180000},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "JPY", exchange: "Japan", buyunits: 32000, sellunits: 1000000},  
{buyCurr: "RUB", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "Russia", buyunits: 1000, sellunits: 1100},  
{buyCurr: "USD", sellCurr: "CNY", exchange: "China", buyunits: 3000, sellunits: 18000},  
{buyCurr: "CNY", sellCurr: "INR", exchange: "China", buyunits: 10000, sellunits: 100000},  
];

function positionSummary(transactions, summaryType) {
    const newList = _(transactions)
        .groupBy(summaryType === 'currency' ? summaryType : `${summaryType}Curr`)
        .map(action => {
            return _.groupBy(action, 'exchange');
        })
        .map(currency => {
            return _.map(currency, exchangeArray => {
                const currency = _.first(exchangeArray)[summaryType === 'currency' ? summaryType : `${summaryType}Curr`];
                const exchange = _.first(exchangeArray)['exchange'];
                let units = _(exchangeArray)
                    .sumBy(summaryType === 'currency' ? 'units' : `${summaryType}units`)
                    .valueOf();
                units = _.multiply(units, summaryType === 'sell' ? -1 : 1);

                return {
                    currency,
                    exchange,
                    units
                };
            });
        })
        .flatten()
        .valueOf();


    console.log(summaryType, newList);
    return newList;
}

const buyUnitSummary = positionSummary(transactions, 'buy');
const sellUnitSummary = positionSummary(transactions, 'sell');
const allUnitSummary = _.concat(buyUnitSummary, sellUnitSummary);
const finalPositionSummary = positionSummary(allUnitSummary, 'currency');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```